# Send email before Excel closes if a change has been made

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, spreadsheet

I have some code written, and tried ChatGPT but have not found success. If anyone can help me sort this out, that would be great.

See code below :

```vb
Private emailScheduled As Boolean ' Flag variable to track if an email is scheduled
Private emailScheduled2 As Boolean

Private originalValues1 As Variant ' Array to store the original values of rng1
Private originalValues2 As Variant ' Array to store the original values of rng2

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim recipient1 As String
    Dim recipient2 As String
    Dim body As String
    
    ' Define the ranges to monitor for changes
    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("E16:E20")
    Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("E22:E25")
    
    ' Check if any changes were made to rng1
    If HasChanges(rng1, originalValues1) Then
        ' Get the file name without the extension
        fileName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)
        
        ' Get the recipient email address for rng1
        recipient1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("E61").Value
        
        ' Create the email body with values separated by " - "
        For Each cell In rng1
            body = body & cell.Offset(0, -4).Value & " - " & cell.Offset(0, -3).Value & " - " & cell.Offset(0, -2).Value & " - " & cell.Value & vbCrLf
        Next cell
        
        ' Create the Outlook application and email objects
        Dim outApp As Object
        Dim outMail As Object
        Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
        
        ' Compose the email for rng1
        With outMail
            .Subject = fileName
            .To = recipient1
            .body = body
            .Send ' or use .Display to review the email before sending
        End With
        
        ' Release the email objects
        Set outMail = Nothing
        Set outApp = Nothing
        
        ' Set the flag variable to indicate that an email for rng1 is scheduled
        emailScheduled = True
    End If
    
    ' Check if any changes were made to rng2
    If HasChanges(rng2, originalValues2) Then
        ' Get the file name without the extension
        fileName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)
        
        ' Get the recipient email address for rng2
        recipient2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("E63").Value
        
        ' Create the email body with values separated by " - "
        body = ""
        For Each cell In rng2
            body = body & cell.Offset(0, -4).Value & " - " & cell.Offset(0, -3).Value & " - " & cell.Offset(0, -2).Value & " - " & cell.Value & vbCrLf
        Next cell
        
        ' Create the Outlook application and email objects
        Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
        
        ' Compose the email for rng2
        With outMail
            .Subject = fileName
            .To = recipient2
            .body = body
            .Send 
        End With
        
        ' Release the email objects
        Set outMail = Nothing
        Set outApp = Nothing
        
        ' Set the flag variable to indicate that an email for rng2 is scheduled
        emailScheduled2 = True
    End If
    
    ' Reset the original values arrays
    originalValues1 = rng1.Value
    originalValues2 = rng2.Value
End Sub

Private Function HasChanges(rng As Range, ByRef originalValues As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim currentValues As Variant
    currentValues = rng.Value
    
    If IsEmpty(originalValues) Then
        originalValues = currentValues
        HasChanges = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    For Each cell In rng
        Dim rowIndex As Long
        Dim columnIndex As Long
        rowIndex = cell.Row - rng.Row + 1
        columnIndex = cell.Column - rng.Column + 1
        
        If currentValues(rowIndex, columnIndex) <> originalValues(rowIndex, columnIndex) Then
            HasChanges = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cell
    
    HasChanges = False
End Function
```

I tried to have excel send an email when the document closed, but only if a change was detected within the ranges mentioned. I could get it to work, when set on a time delay but this is not the best use case with out company. I even tried to set it up on save, but it sent an email every time regardless of a change being made or not.

I am expecting it to store the variable at the opening of the file, detect whether or not a change happened, and if a change did happen an email would be sent.

Answer (score 2):

### Send Email(s) Before Closing a Workbook

**`ThisWorkbook` Module**

- The two procedures that don't start with *Private...* could be located in a standard module, e.g. `Module1`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private WorksheetNames As Variant
Private ValueRanges As Variant
Private OldValues As Variant

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    WorksheetNames = VBA.Array("Info", "Info")
    ValueRanges = VBA.Array("E16:E20", "E22:E25")
    OldValues = GetValues
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ComposeAndSendMails
End Sub

Private Sub ComposeAndSendMails()
    
    Const COPY_COLUMNS As String = "A:E"
    Const ROW_DELIMITER As String = vbLf
    Const COL_DELIMITER As String = " - "
    Dim cIndices(): cIndices = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3, 5) ' skip column 'D'
    Dim Recipients(): Recipients = VBA.Array("E61", "E63")
    
    Dim rLen As Long: rLen = Len(ROW_DELIMITER)
    Dim cLen As Long: cLen = Len(COL_DELIMITER)
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(cIndices)
    
    Dim BaseName As String:
    With ThisWorkbook
        BaseName = Left(.Name, InStrRev(.Name, ".") - 1)
    End With
    
    Dim NewValues(): NewValues = GetValues
    If IsEmpty(GetValues) Then Exit Sub ' covered in 'GetValues'
    
    Dim bData(), n As Long, r As Long, c As Long, eCount As Long
    Dim Body As String, Recipient As String
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(NewValues)
        If IsColumnDifferent(OldValues(n), NewValues(n)) Then
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WorksheetNames(n))
                bData = .Range(ValueRanges(n)).EntireRow _
                    .Columns(COPY_COLUMNS).Value
                Recipient = CStr(.Range(Recipients(n)).Value)
            End With
            For r = 1 To UBound(bData, 1)
                For c = 0 To cUpper
                    Body = Body & bData(r, cIndices(c)) & COL_DELIMITER
                Next c
                Body = Left(Body, Len(Body) - cLen)
                Body = Body & ROW_DELIMITER
            Next r
            Body = Left(Body, Len(Body) - rLen)
            SendMailSimple BaseName, Recipient, Body
            eCount = eCount + 1
            Body = ""
        End If
    Next n

    If eCount > 0 Then
        OldValues = NewValues
    End If
    
    MsgBox IIf(eCount = 0, "No", eCount) & " message" _
        & IIf(eCount = 1, "", "s") & " sent.", _
            IIf(eCount = 0, vbExclamation, vbInformation)

End Sub

Private Function GetValues() As Variant
    
    If IsEmpty(WorksheetNames) Then
        MsgBox "The initial information got lost!", vbExclamation
        Exit Function
    End If
 
    Dim UB As Long: UB = UBound(WorksheetNames)
    Dim Jag(): ReDim Jag(0 To UB)
    
    Dim n As Long
 
    For n = 0 To UB
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WorksheetNames(n)).Range(ValueRanges(n))
            Jag(n) = .Value
        End With
    Next n
        
    GetValues = Jag
 
End Function

Function IsColumnDifferent( _
    ByVal OldData As Variant, _
    ByVal NewData As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnIndex As Long = 1) _
As Boolean
    Dim r As Long
    For r = LBound(OldData, 1) To UBound(OldData, 1)
        If CStr(OldData(r, ColumnIndex)) <> CStr(NewData(r, ColumnIndex)) Then
            IsColumnDifferent = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next r
End Function

Sub SendMailSimple( _
         ByVal Subject As String, _
         ByVal Recipient As String, _
         ByVal Body As String)
    With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
        .Subject = Subject
        .To = Recipient
        .Body = Body
        .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi VBasic, `VBA.Array` ,is that more of a preference than a requirement?

Comment: @Davesexcel It is to ensure a zero-based array no matter the value of `Option Base` like `Split` automatically does.

Comment: @VBasic2008 this worked like a charm. 

In the scenario where we added a third range that went to both email addresses (within the same email instead of two different messages). How would I properly format that on the Dim recipients line?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Dim originalValues1() As Variant
Dim originalValues2() As Variant
    

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' Store ranges into the array
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info")
        originalValues1 = .Range("E16:E20").Value
        originalValues2 = .Range("E22:E25").Value
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim recipient1 As String
    Dim recipient2 As String
    Dim body1 As String
    Dim body2 As String
    Dim shtInfo As Worksheet
    
    Set shtInfo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info")
    Set rng1 = shtInfo.Range("E16:E20")
    Set rng2 = shtInfo.Range("E22:E25")
    
    ' Check for changes in rng1
    If HasChanges(originalValues1, rng1.Value) Then
        ' Get the file name without the extension
        fileName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)
        
        ' Get the recipient email address for rng1
        recipient1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("E61").Value
        
        ' Create the email body with values separated by " - "
        For Each cell In rng1
            body1 = body1 & cell.Offset(0, -4).Value & " - " & cell.Offset(0, -3).Value & " - " & cell.Offset(0, -2).Value & " - " & cell.Value & vbCrLf
        Next cell
        
        With CreateObject("outlook.application").CreateItem(0)
            .Subject = fileName
            .To = recipient1
            .body = body1
            .Display 'use .Send after testing
        End With
    End If
    
        ' Check for changes in rng2
    If HasChanges(originalValues2, rng2.Value) Then
        ' Get the file name without the extension
        fileName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)
        
        ' Get the recipient email address for rng1
        recipient2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("E63").Value
        
        ' Create the email body with values separated by " - "
        For Each cell In rng2
            body2 = body2 & cell.Offset(0, -4).Value & " - " & cell.Offset(0, -3).Value & " - " & cell.Offset(0, -2).Value & " - " & cell.Value & vbCrLf
        Next cell
        
        With CreateObject("outlook.application").CreateItem(0)
            .Subject = fileName
            .To = recipient2
            .body = body2
            .Display 'use .Send after testing
        End With
    End If
    

End Sub

Function HasChanges(arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant) As Boolean
    ' Check if two arrays have the same values
    Dim i As Long
        
    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        If arr1(i, 1) <> arr2(i, 1) Then
            HasChanges = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    
    HasChanges = False
End Function
```